# efficiency of where clause in cypher vs match

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to find 10 posts that were not LIKED by user "mike" using cypher.  Will putting a where clause with a NOT relationship be efficient than matching with an optional relationship then checking if that relationship is null in the where clause?  Specifically I want to make sure it won't do the equivalent of a full table scan and make sure that this is a scalable query.

Here's what I'm using

```
START user=node:node_auto_index(uname:"mike"), 
  posts=node:node_auto_index("postId:*") 
  WHERE not (user-[:LIKES]->posts) 
  RETURN posts SKIP 20 LIMIT 10;
```

Or can I do something where I filter on a MATCH optional relationship

```
START user=node:node_auto_index(uname="mike"),
  posts=node:node_auto_index("postId:*")
  MATCH user-[r?:LIKES]->posts  
  WHERE r IS NULL
  RETURN posts SKIP 100 LIMIT 10;
```

Some quick tests on the console seem to show faster performance in the 2nd approach.  Am I right to assume the 2nd query is faster?  And, if so why?

Comment: your second query is the same as the 1st one, except the SKIP 100 value. shouldn't there be a MATCH clause somewhere?

Comment: Doh, yes, copy and paste error.  Question updated with the correct 2nd example now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think in the first query the engine runs through all `postID` nodes and manually checks the condition of `not (user-[:LIKES]->posts)` for each post ID
whereas in the second example (assuming you use at least v1.9.02) the engine picks up only the post nodes, which actually aren't connected to the user. this is just optimalization where the engine does not go through all postIDs nodes.

if possible, always use the MATCH clause in your queries instead of WHERE, and try to omit the asterix in the declaration `START n=node:index('name:*')`

Comment: If I omit the asterix in the start clause what would the alternative syntax be?

Comment: this is a question related to your graph design - if you must query often in real time that query, maybe it would be better to redesign the graph till you can execute the query without an asterix. sometimes this can't be done, however. could you please provide us with your current db design and goals?

Comment: it's a graph of "users" and "posts".  I use the auto_index on "name" (for users) and "postId" for posts to discriminate the node type.  Users can like posts.  Every day, I want to let users browse a random set of hundreds of posts that they have not yet liked.  For the sake of illustration, let's say that per day there will be millions of posts viewed a day compared with 200,000 posts "liked", 20,000 posts created, and thousands of user registrations.

Comment: hmm, dunno maybe filtering on WHERE just after START declaration could help: `START user=node:node_auto_index(uname="mike")
  MATCH user-[r:LIKES]->posts  
  WITH MAX(Id(posts)) as mx,user START p=node:node_auto_index("postId:*")  MATCH user-[r?:LIKE]-p WHERE Id(p)>mx AND Id(p)<(mx+100) and r is NULL
  RETURN p LIMIT 10;` ?

Comment: fix: `START user=node:node_auto_index(uname="mike")
  MATCH user-[r:LIKES]->posts  
  WITH MAX(Id(posts)) as mx,user START p=node:node_auto_index("postId:*") WHERE Id(p)>mx AND Id(p)<(mx+100)  MATCH user-[r?:LIKE]-p WHERE  r is NULL
  RETURN p LIMIT 10;` ?`

Comment: anyway, this sounds like a job for a regular sql db, or more precisely - there is no need to use graph db since there are no traversals needed. maybe neo4j isn't the way you want it. i would simply pick up 1000 random posts and then filter first 100 on these posts whether or not the user liked them - it's less computational then picking all post user didn't like and filter a 100 on them.

Comment: this would just be one of use cases.  The other uses cases we have that look for recommendations and collaboarative filtering would need the graph traversals.  Trying to figure out if we can have one graph db that fits all our needs.

Comment: yes, maybe try to create a new question for that problem. this question is already out of attention.